# How to get a userID from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Today i try to get some child of `firebase` database, i dont know if my structure is a best of my case so i have a app like a "rappi" and i have child empresa and child if user id like this:

[image: image of estructure]

so i want to get child inside pet shop and user Logged is inside farmacia. i want to know is a better method to get id from empresa.

```
DatabaseReference produtosRef = firebaseRef
            .child("empresa")
            .child( "How i get this?" )
            .child(UserID);
```

I don't know how to get a second instance

Edit1: I want to get user id if out pass "petshop" or " farmácia"

Comment: Please indicate what is the exact data that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already had a custom class to store objects. If not, create it!

```
class YourClass{
    public String categoria;
    public String email;
    public String uid;
    ///....and some attributes as in your pic you posted
}
```

Next, at somewhere in your code. to get all objects from database. you need to add child event listener to your firebase reference.

```
ArrayList < YourClass > objects = new ArrayList < > ();
    DatabaseReference dataRef =
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("empresa").child("farmacia");
    dataRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {}

     @Override
     public void onCancelled() {
        System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String arg1) {
        YourClass object = 
           (YourClass(dataSnapshot.getValue(YourClass.class));
        if (object != null) objects.add(object);
        //from now you have object so you can access and modify or do anything with it
     }

     @Override
     public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry i think i dont explained correct, i want to get user ID with out pass a "farmacia" or "petshop"